# When planning a FFT, can I use the same plan for an inverse FFT?

Tags: cuda, fft

I am working with a 3D array of real floats.

In one part of my code, I am supposed to take a 3DFFT of these values, and then dot the resulting complex matrix with another matrix of floats. (dot = pointwise multiplication)

Then I take the inverse FFT and update the initial array.

What is important when you do the first `cufftPlan3d()`?
i.e.What is the Plan really looking for?

Does the plan just need to see the dimensions and the type of the array to work quickly, or is it also looking at the magnitudes of the real and complex parts?

I am trying to use the plan as little as possible so that I can compute the transforms faster, but I also want the FFTs (and the iFFTs) to be as fast as possible as this is the bottleneck of the code.

My first thought is that I would make a plan before the initial FFT and then make another plan after the resulting dot product/FFT for the inverse FFT and then use these 2 plans everywhere later in the loop.

Thanks for any suggestions.

Answer (score 2):

You should definitely be able to create just one plan and reuse it everywhere in the loop, as long as the type and size of the transform does not change.  It sounds like that is the case for you.  In fact, you can use the same plan for both forward (FFT) and reverse (iFFT) transforms as long as the type and size are the same, since `CUFFT_FORWARD` / `CUFFT_REVERSE` are parameters for `cufftExec*()`, not for `cufftPlan*()`.

If you have multiple sizes and types to support, create a separate plan for each type/size combination at startup (if you know them ahead of time).

Comment: may be you can add an example to explain a bit. Because many people will be using R2C and C2R transforms for forward and reverse which can not be handled with one type. The only case it is possible is if both the inputs and outputs are complex (C2C and Z2Z transforms).